# Remove Cookies - Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension

Below is my code to remove cookies from a website via chrome API:

```
chrome.cookies.getAll({ 'domain': 'example.com' }, async function(cookies) {
  console.log('startingCookies::', cookies)
  for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
    await chrome.cookies.remove({'url': 'https://example.com', 'name': cookies[i].name})
  }

  const finalCookies = await chrome.cookies.getAll({'domain': 'example.com'})
  console.log('finalCookies::', finalCookies)
})
```

Although `chrome.cookies.remove` returned the `removed cookie objects` but `finalCookies` are still the same as `startingCookies` after removing.

May I know the actual way of removing these cookies using chrome API?

Comment: Assuming you have correctly declared `host_permissions` in manifest.json, the `url` is probably incorrect in remove() - e.g. the cookies may use `path` or they are `http` not `https`.

Comment: @wOxxOm but the callback in chrome.cookies.remove does return the removed cookie objects. This would mean that the url is correct, isn't it?

Comment: Sounds like a bug then.